# Why is my React Route not working even with exact prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following situation where there is a list of Posts.
If you click on one post, it will route to "/posts/1" for instance.
However, in my code below when I click on any one post, I can see the URL changing to "/posts/1" but the page immediately routes back to "/posts" and I cannot understand why.
Shouldn't the "exact" in the second route () make sure that exactly that path is being sent?

```js
// Blog Component
<Switch>
    <Route path="/new-post" component={NewPost} />
    <Route path="/posts" exact component={Posts} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/posts" />
</Switch>

// Posts Component
class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        selectedPostId: null
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ posts: response.data.slice(0, 4) });
        });
    }

    onPostSelected = (id) => {
        this.props.history.push( '/posts/' + id );
    }

    render() {
        let posts = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
            return (
                    // <Link to={'/' + post.id} key={post.id}>
                        <Post 
                            key={post.id} 
                            title={post.title} 
                            author={post.author}
                            onClicked={() => this.onPostSelected(post.id)}/>
                    // </Link>
                   )
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="Posts">
                    {posts}
                </section>
                <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/:id'} exact component={FullPost} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: can you share your complete code in sandbox so that i could changes

Comment: <Route path="/posts/:id" exact component={New_Component} /> need to make changes for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have exact specified on the top level route i.e `/Posts` and hence the inner nested route won't match and instead it will redirect to `/Posts`

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/new-post" component={NewPost} />
    <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/posts" />
</Switch>
```

Remove exact from `/posts` route and your code would work.

Comment: I would still like to understand the behavior though. Why is it not showing me a blank page? Why does it redirect to "/posts" afterwards?

Comment: ok so since `/posts/:id` cannot be matched as its parent itself won't match and hence `posts` component wont render, now that you haven't mentioned exact props on `<Redirect from="/" to="/posts" />`, `/posts/:id` will match `/` since `/` is a prefix to this route and hence will redirect to `/posts`